# How to control C Macro Precedence

Tags: c, macros

```
#define VAL1CHK 20

#define NUM 1

#define JOIN(A,B,C) A##B##C

int x = JOIN(VAL,NUM,CHK);
```

With above code my expectation was

```
int x = 20;
```

But i get compilation error as macro expands to

```
int x = VALNUMCHK; // Which is undefined
```

How to make it so that `NUM` is replaced first and the `JOIN` is used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can redirect the `JOIN` operation to another macro, which then does the actual pasting, in order to enforce expansion of its arguments:

```
#define VAL1CHK 20
#define NUM 1
#define JOIN1(A, B, C) A##B##C
#define JOIN(A, B, C) JOIN1(A, B, C)

int x = JOIN(VAL,NUM,CHK);
```

This technique is often used with the pasting and stringification operators in macros.

Comment: This is very similar to how you implement precedence by reordering the grammatical rules of a parser generator.